# Powershell Script to check drive letter for shared drives, then check those drives to see if Volume Shadow Copy is enabled

Tags: powershell, registry

First Post here. First off, I really have little experience with scripting, so thank you for your kindness.

I have a script I found that can somewhat get the drive letters that have shares on it

```
Push-Location
Set-Location 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares'
Get-Item . |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty property |
ForEach-Object {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{"property"=$_;"Value" = (Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_}
} |
Format-Table property, value -AutoSize
Pop-Location
```

The "value" results are long:

`{CSCFlags=0, MaxUses=4294967295, Path=C:\location, Permissions=x...}`

Ideally, all I need is the drive letter. Then I would like to use the drive letter found to see if Volume Shadow Copy is enabled on said drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty horrible, and I'm *sure* there's a better way to address your problem, but the below effectively looks at your public shares, finds the drive letter, looks up the `VolumeID` for that drive letter and then checks to see if the `VolumeID` is present in the shadow copy config:

```powershell
$paths = $(gwmi win32_share | ? {$_.name -notmatch '.*\$$' } | select -expandproperty path) -replace '([A-Z]:).*', '$1'

foreach($p in $($paths | sort-object -Unique)) {
  $deviceId = gwmi win32_volume | ? { $_.driveletter -eq $p } | select -expandproperty deviceid
  if( $(gwmi win32_shadowcopy | ? {$_.volumename -eq $deviceId }) ) {
    Write-Host "$($p) Volume Shadow Copy enabled"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "$($p) No Volume Shadow Copy"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will create an array of all drive letters on a target server and then check each using wmi to see if volume shadow storage is present.

```
# Specify host to check
$serverName = "localhost"
# Create an empty array to hold our drive letters
$driveLetterArray = @()

# Use wmi to get all share paths
(get-wmiobject win32_share -computername $serverName).path | foreach {
   # Get just the drive letter of the share path
   $driveLetter = $_.split(":")[0]
   # Send drive letter to array if it doesn't already exist in that array
   if (($driveLetter) -and ($driveLetterArray -notcontains $driveLetter)) {
        $driveLetterArray += $driveLetter
   }
} 

# Check if that drive letter has shadowstorage
foreach ($letter in $driveLetterArray) {
    # Clean up the letter variable so it will be able to match results from gwmi win32_volume
    $letter = $letter + ":\"
    $deviceID = (gwmi win32_volume -computername $serverName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $letter}).deviceID
    # Clean up the deviceID variable so it will be able to match results from gwmi win32_shadowstorage
    $deviceID = $deviceID.TrimStart("\\?\")
    $deviceID = "Win32_Volume.DeviceID=`"\\\\?\\" + $deviceID + "\`""
    $shadowQuery = gwmi win32_shadowstorage -computername $serverName | Where-Object {$_.Volume -eq $deviceID}
    # Report findings to the user
    if ($shadowQuery) {
        "Volume shadow enabled on drive $letter"
    } else {
        "Volume shadow NOT enabled on drive $letter"
    }
}
```